# Get-Childitem including the directory itself

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

This is probably a dumb question but is there a way to get a directory and all of it's subdirectories using either Get-Item or get-ChildItem?  Or would I need to use both?

Ex.  I have the following directory structure:

[image]

'IT' is the parent directory containing both 'abc' and 'xyz' directories.  I want to take some action on the 'abc' directory and all of it's sub directories but not on 'xyz' or it's subs.

If I were to use something like this I can take action on 123 and blue but not abc.

```
$root = "k:\IT\abc"
Get-ChildItem $root -Path $root -Directory -Recurse
```

If I were to use something like this it will take action on abc and its subs but also on xyz and its subs which is not what I want.

```
$root = "k:\IT"
Get-ChildItem $root -Path $root -Directory -Recurse
```

I didn't see a way to do this with Get-Item.  Any thoughts?  I know this is probably very basic but I am still learning.

I looked and did not find anything that addressed this.

Comment: `@(Get-Item K:\It; Get-ChildItem $root -Directory -Recurse)` sounds good. If `-Exclude` would exclude the matched folder and all it's childs that would work but is not the case unfortunately

Comment: Meant `@(Get-Item $root; Get-ChildItem $root -Directory -Recurse)` typo

Comment: So I tried $rootArray = @(Get-Item $root; Get-ChildItem $root -Directory -Recurse) but it is giving me "Get-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'system.Object[]' "  Am I mis-formatting the command?